Does .NET Framework developer pack v4.8.1 include runtime v4.8.1?
I'm just curious.
I understand what the developer pack is for and what the runtime is for.
But I'm wondering if I install ".NET Framework v4.8.1 Developer Pack" (NDP481-DevPack-ENU.exe) on Windows 10.
Do I need to install Runtime as well (NDP481-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe)?
Logic tells me that DevPack must include runtime same version + additional libraries for developers. Is that correct?

Yes, you're correct, installing the .NET Framework 4.8.1 Developer Pack will also automatically install the .NET Framework 4.8.1 Runtime at the same time. You don't have to manually install the Runtime separately.
I tested this on a fresh installation of Windows 10 22H2 (which comes with 4.8.0) and verified with ASoft .NET Version Detector 22 R2.

Thank you for confirmation. It was confusing for me since I couldn't find any Microsoft article that explicitly claims that. But when I checked the registry keys the value of the Release entry matched to 4.8.1 version. Then I started the installation of the Runtime and it went like first time installation.
